# How to do a rake task at a specific time of day per user's timezone in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to perform some maintenance on each user's information, but I want it to only happen around midnight per the user's timezone. The user's table has a `time_zone` column that defaults to Eastern.

So far I have the following rake task set to run every hour:

```
task update_user_stuff: :environment do
  users = []
  User.all.each do |user|
    b = Time.now - 29.minutes
    e = Time.now + 30.minutes
    if (b..e).cover?(Time.now.in_time_zone(user.time_zone).beginning_of_day)
      users << user
    end
  end    
  unless users.blank?
    users.each do |user|
      # user maintenance here
    end
  end
end
```

That code seems to work in my testing with a testing database of 20 users, taking about 4 seconds to complete. My concern is that on a production server with thousands of users, it'll be inefficient and that relying on manually setting a time window (lines 4-5) will lead to problems.

**What's a better way to write this task?**

Edit for even more clarity: **I know how to run this task periodically.** I'm asking if the task itself can be written better.

Comment: Use a gem like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever). Happy?

Comment: The code above is executed by a cron job.

Comment: Any memory of how you ended up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `whenever gem` https://github.com/javan/whenever which uses `cron` to run tasks.

You can setup a `whenever cron job` to go through all users and check their timezones. If the time matches, then you can something specific for that user.

Example: Setup `whenever cron job` to run task every hour. This task calls a method that checks user's timezones and if the timezone matches, it a condition then it calls another `rake task` or `method` for that specific user.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with how to run the task. I'm aware of how to run cron jobs and how to use the whenever gem.